# The sender address of a forwarded meeting request does not include “on behalf of” as expected

Tags: exchange, outlook

We have an Exchange 2010 environment with a mix of Outlook 2010 and 2013 clients.  We have the following issue when forwarding meeting invites:

User A sends a meeting request to user B, user B forwards the meeting request to user C but it appears to have come from user A only - it does not show that it was sent by user B on behalf of user A.

Is there a way to change this so that user C will know that it was sent by user B?  This is an issue for us because we had a situation where user B added some comments to the meeting invite before forwarding it to user C.  User C thought that the comments were made by user A when in fact they were not.

I'm not finding much on the internet that directly addresses this issue, so I'm hoping someone here can lead me in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I know that your final purpose is to prevent recipients editing the email to others.

In this case use IRM

IRM also helps allow or restrict recipient actions such as forwarding a message to other recipients, printing a message or attachment, or extracting message or attachment content by copying and pasting.

More details to refer: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638140(v=exchg.150).aspx

You can also use Set-IRMConfiguration cmdlet to configure IRM protection on both OWA and ActiveSync.

More details to refer: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd979792(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: I don't necessarily want to restrict the ability to forward the meeting invite - I'd like the message to indicate that it was sent on behalf of the original meeting organizer (user A) when it gets forwarded, so that user C knows that the message written by user B in the forward is in fact from user B and not user A.  Is that even possible?